# How do I double each character in a file?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILE_READ "prive.txt"

int main() {
  FILE * filp;
  int count = 1;
  char c;
  filp = fopen(FILE_READ, "r");

  if (filp == NULL)
      printf("file not found\n");

  while((c = fgetc(filp)) != EOF) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(c); i++){
      strncpy()
    }
  }
  printf("worrds = %s\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

How do I double each character in a file?

Example:

- Before: Hi
- After: HHii

One more example:

- Hello
- HHeelllloo

Comment: This is entirely C code but for `<iostream>` and `<fstream>` ...which you don't even use. Are you writing C++ or C?

Comment: The `str` prefix in e.g. `strlen` has the meaning *string*. As in null-terminated sequence of characters. The length of a single character is one.

Comment: I’m using C++.  Sorry

Comment: Then please only add C++ tag for your question.

Comment: As for your problem, read every characters in the file, and print it twice.

Comment: Lastly (from me), note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an ***`int`***, which is rather crucial for that comparison against the integer value `EOF`.

Comment: `printf("worrds = %s\n", c);` - the `%s` conversion requires a C-style null-terminated string argument, like say `"hello\0"`, where `c` is a single character.  This will crash your program.  You're much better off using e.g. `std::cout << c;`

Comment: @Hadibadimadi I have added a non-fstream solution to my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66799497/14749002).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program opens the file `input.txt` and prints each character twice into `output.txt`. That also means that each line break is duplicated though.

Example of the `input.txt` file:

```
Hello, World!
```

Example of the `output.txt` file:

```
HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!
```

### Using <iostream> and <fstream>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    std::ifstream file_in("input.txt");
    std::ofstream file_out("output.txt");
    if (!file_in.is_open() || !file_out.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (file_in.get(c)) {
        file_out << c << c;
    }
    file_in.close();
    file_out.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Using <stdio.h> and <stdlib.h>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    FILE *file_in = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *file_out = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (!file_in || !file_out) {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(file_in)) != EOF) {
        fprintf(file_out, "%c%c", c, c);
    }
    fclose(file_in);
    fclose(file_out);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The second program does not work. 
  fprintf(file_out, "%c%c", c, c)
Program said that c is none initialisations.how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` to open the input and output file buffers. Use `std::istream::get` to retrieve each `char` of the file and then output it twice to your `FILE_WRITE`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define FILE_READ "./prive.txt"
#define FILE_WRITE "./output.txt"

int main()
{
    char c;

    std::ifstream i(FILE_READ);
    std::ofstream o(FILE_WRITE);

    while (i.get(c)) 
        o << c << c;      

    i.close();
    o.close();

    return 0;

}
```

And since you asked, if you would not like to use `fstream`, you could go for the solution below, which adds the input and output files to a buffer with `fopen()`, and by means of `fgetc()` stores each `char` of the text file in the `c` variable. Then, by means of `fprintf()`, the char is added twice to the output file.

```
#include <iostream>

#define FILE_READ "./prive.txt"
#define FILE_WRITE "./output.txt"

int main()
{
    FILE* input = fopen(FILE_READ, "r");
    FILE* output = fopen(FILE_WRITE, "w");
    signed char c;

    while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        fprintf(output, "%c%c", c, c);
    }
    
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the input file in "read" mode;
2. Open an output file in "write" mode;
3. Read one character from the input file until reach EOF:
   Write the character to the output file;
   Repeat the write operation;
4. Close both files.
5. [Optional] remove the input file, rename the output file to the original name.